# Xamarin forms grid layout size is reducing continuously

Tags: layout, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, grid

We are facing issues in Xamarin grid layout, the sizes are defined in the OnAppearing method. every time if we call OnAppearing method, the size of grid is reducing continuously, not getting exact issue

here is the code

```
  gridLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition(){
            Height = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star),
        });
        gridLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition(){
            Height = new GridLength(5, GridUnitType.Star),
        });
        gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
        {
            Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star),
        });
        gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition(){
            Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star),
        });
        gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition(){
            Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star),
        });
        gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition(){
            Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star),
        });
        gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition(){
            Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star),
        });


        var productIndex = 0;
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 2; rowIndex++)
        {
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 5; columnIndex++)
            {
                if (productIndex >= CategoryArray.Count)
                {
                    break;
                }
                var category = CategoryArray[productIndex];
                productIndex += 1;
                var categoriesView = new CategoriesView
                {
                    BackgroundColor = Color.White
                };

                if(category.Image == null){
                    categoriesView.CategoriesImage.Source = "category_logo";
                }else{
                    categoriesView.CategoriesImage.Source = category.Image;
                }

                //categoriesView.BackgroundColor = Color.Olive;
                categoriesView.TextLabel.Text = category.Name;
                categoriesView.CategoryId = category.Id.ToString();
                gridLayout.Children.Add(categoriesView, columnIndex, rowIndex);

                //gridLayout.BackgroundColor = Color.Beige;
            }
        }
```

when ever OnAppearing is calling the page is reloading (the is the feature) and the grid size is reducing continuously.

Comment: Is the gridLayout Grid created in OnAppearing, the constructor, Xaml, or where?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare the Grid structure only once, ideally in Constructor (or in XAML which is called in the constructor). Whenever OnAppearing is called, you are adding 2 new rows and 5 new columns to the existing Grid hence its size is reducing.

Also, by looking at the elements adding logic you've written, you should probably be using ListView with a Grid ViewCell and set the ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection so that it will update automatically